# Sessions not setting using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code which uses jquery and ajax to send a request to the other page i.e.

```
<html>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="button" id="butt"  value="button11111111111111" >
 </html>
 <script>

    $("#butt").on('click',function(e)
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type:'POST',
                url:'testmysql.php',
                data:
                {
                    product_type:"cake";
                }

            });

    });


</script>
```

When i click the above button it should send the request and data  to the other file *testmysql.php*

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['type']=$_POST['product_type'];
echo $_SESSION['type'];
?>
```

However , when i refresh the other page after clicking the button i do not see any kind of echo and it gives me a notice stating

> Undefined index: product_type

Since, i am new to ajax and jquery is there anything i am missing ?if yes,then what should i do to make this work ?

Thanks!

**Note:** Both of them are in the same directory.

Comment: why you are refreshing the page. you are sending a ajax request to the **testmysql.php** page.

Comment: i have sent a request to the other page which will set the data.So in order to view that i should refresh the page right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the semicolon(`;`) from this statement,

```
product_type:"cake";
                   ^
```

otherwise it will give you *syntax error*. And now comes to your issue.

> when i refresh the other page after clicking the button i do not see any kind of echo and it gives me a notice stating *Undefined index: product_type*

That because when you refresh **testmysql.php** page, the `$_POST` array would be empty, and there would be no index named `product_type` in `$_POST` array. You can verify it using `var_dump($_POST);`.

On **testmysql.php** page you can check whether `$_POST['product_type']` is set or not like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['product_type'])){
        $_SESSION['type']=$_POST['product_type'];
        echo $_SESSION['type'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: @user5871514 On **testmysql.php** page you can do something like this: `if(isset($_SESSION['type'])){ echo $_SESSION['type']; }`

Answer (score 1):

- you added the `;` at the end of the data object. remove it and try.
- and you are sending a ajax request to the **testmysql.php** page, the `$_POST['product_type']` will available when you are send the request. when you refresh the page the you are not sending any post request to **testmysql.php** page.